# When I try authentication I get maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: django, django-authentication

```
    state = "Please log in below"
    if request.POST:
       username = request.POST.get('username')
       password = request.POST.get('password')
       user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
       if user is not None:
               if user.is_active:
                   login(request, user)
                   state = "You're successfully logged in!"
       else:
            state = "Your account is not active, please log back in."
    else:
        state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."
return render(request, template_name, {'state': state})
```

If I enter incorrect user name or password, it catches it. But when I enter the right credentials it gives me "maximum recursion depth exceeded".

Comment: Is the function you've pasted here named "login"? Are you calling yourself recursively on accident?

Comment: Yup the function name was login. I changed it. It works now. Is there docummentation on that? Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is not so much a documentation issue as a fundamental of programming. When you call a function by name, and your function calls itself, that is called "recursion" (please read relevant wikipedia entries, etc.). Too much recursion causes errors like the one you're seeing here, or errors that look like "stack overflow" or "maximum stack exceeded". You may also want to google around for a quick rundown on what "stack" and "heap" mean.